# Total Unique users for 30 days

Tags: mysql

Have a problem here that is I need to calculate the total of unque users for 30 days for each of the date. I mean for today it is the sum of unique between the range today-30 days and for yesterday it is yesterday-30 days and so on. Table structure is :

```
date        uid   visits
27-06-2013   11     40
27-06-2013   14     40
26-06-2013   13     45
25-06-2013   11     20
24-06-2013   12     40
```

It goes on like this. What I need is the sum for each day.

Comment: Why not use a DATE data type for dates? Once you've fixed that, prepare a sqlfiddle AND show us what the desired result set would actually look like.

Comment: @Barmar Checked the Trailing Sum Query. But I don't understand the first answer and second is just selecting for 3 days. So here I need to do this for 30 days ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, those answers are not very good for a long period like this. Use Kickstart's answer.

Comment: My reading of the question is that you want all the unique users over several 30 day time period. In one of those time periods a user could be recorded on the 1st day and the 30th day and so would be counted once. So with your example data there would be 4 unique users. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as the following should work fine:

```
SELECT
    `date`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `uid`) as `unique_visits`
FROM
    `foo`
WHERE
    `date` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY
    `date`
```

[**SQLFiddle DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b21d/1/0)

Comment: But this will only give the counts. Not the SUM

Comment: The login date is most likely a timestamp, so you'll need to convert it.

Comment: @AlwinAugustin You wanted **unique** counts for the day, right?

Comment: @AlwinAugustin What are you trying to sum?

Comment: He wants a trailing 30 day total for each date in the table, not just today.

Comment: @AleksG I am trying sum the counts. I mean for today it is sum of counts of counts in the range today-30 days. For yesterday it is in the range ysterday-30 days. I mean for today it is sum of counts from '02-06-2013' to '02-07-2013' For yesterday it is '01-06-2013' to '01-07-2013' and so on

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have read your question correctly and you date field is of data type date then something like this maybe:-

```
SELECT Sub1.EndDate, COUNT(DISTINCT a.uid)
FROM SomeTable a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT date AS EndDate, DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS StartDate
    FROM SomeTable
) Sub1
ON a.date BETWEEN Sub1.StartDate AND Sub1.EndDate
```

This is using a subselect to get each range of 30 days, then joining that back against the table to get all the records in that date range and doing a count distinct to find all the distinct users

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'Sub1.date' in 'field list'

Comment: Try it now (I had aliased the date field to EndDate but forgot to change it on the top select)

Answer (score 0):

```
Consider this example. It provides a rolling sum on values within 3 points of the current value

SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT x.i, SUM(y.i) FROM ints x JOIN ints y ON y.i BETWEEN x.i-3 AND x.i GROUP BY x.i;
+---+----------+
| i | SUM(y.i) |
+---+----------+
| 0 |        0 |
| 1 |        1 |
| 2 |        3 |
| 3 |        6 |
| 4 |       10 |
| 5 |       14 |
| 6 |       18 |
| 7 |       22 |
| 8 |       26 |
| 9 |       30 |
+---+----------+
```